# Message Passing with Native Application Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, plugins, message-passing, nativeapplication

I am new in Plugin development.I heard from blog that Chrome is going to stop support on NPAPI plugins.I developed one native application in Mac, i am trying to make it as a plugin. But i didn't find a perfect tutorial that how the native application and plugin will interact. I gone through the chrome developers page, but its only gave some basic idea about the message passing. But for a new developer it is quite difficult to understand. Please help me in this. It would be great

Comment: The following answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134665/how-to-send-message-from-native-app-to-chrome-extension/19866346

Comment: Also, I would suggest in future questions - mention which platform/etc the native code is written in - ie: objective-c? Python? C#/mono? :)

Comment: I developed the application using Objective c.