# Debugging Chrome native messaging

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I am a beginner in developing Chrome extensions. I am trying to achieve a native messaging between my extension and a C++ code. Here is the C++ code

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
// Define our message
char message[] = "{\"text\": \"This is a response message\"}";
// Collect the length of the message
unsigned int len = strlen(message);
// We need to send the 4 bytes of length information
printf("%c%c%c%c", (char) (len & 0xff),
                   (char) ((len>>8) & 0xFF),
                   (char) ((len>>16) & 0xFF),
                   (char) ((len>>24) & 0xFF));
// Now we can output our message
printf("%s", message);
return 0;
```

}

The problem is that the extension does receive any thing and I don't know how to debug the program. I've tried opening Chrome from the terminal so that errors are displayed, but nothing is displayed there. here is the code from the background.js

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.my_company.my_application');

port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("Received" + msg);
});

port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
    console.log("Disconnected");
});
```

Any way I could debug the program?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134665/how-to-send-message-from-native-app-to-chrome-extension/19866346

Answer (score 0):

You can run Chrome with logging enabled and then review the errors using Sawbuck - a handy GUI designed just for that. If the problem is with Chrome, it might shed some light.

see here - http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to debug but no end-end IDE like debug exists.

1. to debug your background and content scripts--- *background and page content section in chrome tools*
2. to debug the host --- open chrome from terminal with logging enabled
3. Also native messaging API offers you some methods which will return appropriate error messages like, `runtime.lastError`

   [can refer this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect)