# Use a C exe as Nativehost application instead python in chrome NativeHost messaging

Tags: python, c, google-chrome-extension, file-handling

I took [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/) chrome app example for NativeMessaging, it allows a python program to run and talk back to app. I converted it to extension and am trying to replace the python script with a C program but my C program is not able to communicate back to extension.my question is, Is it possible to use C instead python (looks possible to me, at least). if it is possible then what am I doing wrong?

Code for replacement of python:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 2

 int t1=0;
void *thr_fwrite(void *arg) {
        FILE *p;
        if(arg==NULL)
                p=(FILE*)arg;
        char buffer[200]={"0023 hello how are you    q"};;
        int len=27;
while(1)
{
        if(t1==0){
        fwrite(buffer,len,sizeof(char),stdout);
        fwrite(buffer,len,sizeof(char),p);
        t1=1;
        }

}
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
/* thread function */
void *thr_fread(void *arg) {
        FILE *p;
        if(arg==NULL)
                p=(FILE*)arg;
        char buffer[200]={""};
        int len=0;
while(1)
{
        if(t1==1){
        fread(buffer,1,sizeof(int),stdin);
        if(strcmp(buffer,"")==0)
                exit(0);
        len=atoi(buffer);
        if(len==0 || len>200)
                exit(0);
        fread(buffer,len,sizeof(char),stdin);
        fwrite(buffer,len,sizeof(char),p);
        t1=0;
        }

}
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pthread_t thr[NUM_THREADS];
  int i, rc;

FILE *p;
FILE *q;


p=fopen("~/temp.txt","w+");
q=fopen("~/temp1.txt","w+");
  /* create threads */
    if ((rc = pthread_create(&thr[0], NULL, thr_fwrite, &p))) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ((rc = pthread_create(&thr[1], NULL, thr_fread, &q))) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  /* block until all threads complete */
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
    pthread_join(thr[i], NULL);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

partial code for chrome extension code is:

```
function ConnectHost() {
  var hostName = "com.example.nativehost";
  port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
  if(port == null)
  {
     alert("Could not connect to Host Client");
  }
  else
  { 
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
  }     

function onDisconnected() {
  alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
  port = null;
}

function onNativeMessage(message) {
  alert(message);
  SendToNative("exit");
}
```

Do we have any example already which uses C instead of python?

Comment: I am sorry but i dont understand your comment.

Comment: Could you please spend some time cleaning up the formatting of your code?  It is difficult to follow in its current formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome doesn't care (and cannot know) what's on the other side as long as the program answers in expected format (see [Native Messaging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol)). Which does not seem to be the case here from a brief glance at your code.

Chrome will only accept messages consisting of 4-byte length header + UTF-8 encoded string that is valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

There are [some examples of C Native Hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134665/how-to-send-message-from-native-app-to-chrome-extension) on SO.

An important caveat to consider is that the communication should be in binary mode, not text mode:

> Windows-only: Make sure that the program's I/O mode is set to `O_BINARY`. By default, the I/O mode is `O_TEXT`, which corrupts the message format as line breaks (\n = 0A) are replaced with Windows-style line endings (\r\n = 0D 0A). The I/O mode can be set using `__setmode`.

Comment: The example mentioned in the link posted, were helpful.