# Get the Computer Name Using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, computer-name

I want to get the computer name using jquery. I tried using ActiveX Object but it will only run on IE browser. Is there is another way to get the computer name using jquery. I tried that code.

```
 var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');  
 alert(network.computerName);
```

Can u any one help me..

Comment: Even on that navigator it will probably be blocked on mostly computers. I don't think you would get that information without client extended code. Also define what you expect by computer name, host name, Wins name, etc.

Comment: no, there is no way a browser can access the underlying operating system like that at all

Comment: @guest271314 cleary if the user is already showing a solution for IE he is not working on a Firefox/Chrome extension.

Comment: @SamuelNeff You are ignoring _"I tried using ActiveX Object but it will only run on IE browser."_ OP is asking how the procedure can be accomplished, and used ie as an example of a browser accessing the local filesysystem or a shell.

Comment: @SamuelNeff  `NativeMessaging` is available at edge browser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging

Comment: @guest271314 …in Edge extensions. Not in web pages.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. This information is not available to web sites.

The ActiveX approach outlined in your question won't even work in current versions of Internet Explorer, as the `WScript.Network` ActiveX object is not marked as safe for scripting.

Comment: The requirement is possible using `NativeMessaging`

Comment: @guest271314 That would involve installing a browser extension and/or a native application on the user's computer, which isn't something that a web site can do on its own.

Comment: "You can't" is not accurate as to the requirement. Protocol handler could also be utilized.

Comment: @guest271314 The implication is that the OP wants a method that will work in a "stock" web browser, without requiring the user to change browser security settings or install additional software / addons.

Comment: See OP at _"Is there is another way to get the computer name using jquery."_ .  _"without requiring the user to change browser security settings or install additional software / addons"_ does not appear at Question.

Comment: @guest271314 the default for any question about the web, jquery, javascript would be in a browser unless specified otherwise. Your insistence that this is possible without clearly qualifying it "within an extension" is not helpful.

Comment: @SamuelNeff What are you talking about. The entire browser is an "extension" that is capable of communicating in multiple different protocols and using different application interfaces - including `WebAssembly` or even `ProcessingInstruction`. What a user chooses to do with the resources available in a modern browser is their choice,  there are many choices available. The requirement is possible using a browser.

Comment: @guest271314 …are you sure you understand what we mean by "a browser extension"?

Comment: @duskwuff "a browser extension" does not appear at text of Question "Is there is another way" does appear at text of Question.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there is another way to get the computer name

You can utilize `NativeMessaging` to achieve requirement at Firefox and Chromium, Chrome.

Comment: This is only applicable for an extension. It cannot be used from a web page.

Comment: @SamuelNeff _"This is only applicable for an extension. It cannot be used from a web page"_ That is not correct. An extension can communicate with a web page. _"used from a web page"_ does not appear at Question.

Comment: Web page is very clearly the context of the question.

Comment: @user2979432 See https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/Native_Messaging, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging, https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging, http://webassembly.org/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134665/how-to-send-message-from-native-app-to-chrome-extension/