# How to send message from native app written in Node.js to Chrome extension?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

<sup>*This question is a continuation of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134665/how-to-send-message-from-native-app-to-chrome-extension), because there hasn't been any answer with Nodejs code in that question, 6 years now.*</sup>

I use Chrome 79 and Nodejs 13, in windows 10.

I have a Nodejs script(see below) acting as the native messaging host, and a Chrome extension.
I want to send messages from the Nodejs script to my extension.

I know how to receive messages in my Chrome extension - here is its background.js:

```js
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('my_messaging_host');

port.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  console.log("Received: " + message);
});
```

The Nodejs script I have(see below) is the native messaging host. I used as a reference the only Nodejs messaging host code example I could find, [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging#App_side).
I've noticed that this Nodejs code example was added in that MDN wiki page very recently, 10 days ago, and it **has issues/needs improvement**.

Anyway, I've modified it as follows, but I'm getting the following error from my extension when sending messages: `Failed to connect: Error when communicating with the native messaging host`, which, based on the docs *indicates an incorrect implementation of the communication protocol in the native messaging host.*

**So, why is my Nodejs script not working ok?

Could you please give me a working Nodejs host code example?**

```js
function sendMessage(msg) {
    var buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg));

    var header = Buffer.alloc(4);
    header.writeUInt32LE(buffer.length, 0);

    var data = Buffer.concat([header, buffer]);
    process.stdout.write(data);
}
```

---

For reference, various native messaging host examples:

- [Google Native Messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#examples): in Python.
- [MDN Native Messaging docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging#App_side): in Nodejs and Python 2 & 3,
- as answers to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134665/how-to-send-message-from-native-app-to-chrome-extension) mentioned above: in C, C++, C# and Python.

Comment: I hope you're following the guide (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#examples) thoroughly, like adding registry keys, right? Please confirm.

Comment: Also, did you tried Google's example: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging

Comment: @Ashutosh  Yes, I'm following the guide exactly. And yes, I've tried the Google's example and it's working but the host in that example (the 'native-messaging-example-host' file) is irrelevant because it's written in Python, while I want one in NodeJS.

Comment: Chrome's Native Messaging suggests that `Error when communicating with the native messaging host.` is due to *an incorrect implementation of the communication protocol in the native messaging host.* But, I can't see such an error in your code. Could you use `sendMessage()` without `decodeMessage()` to send a dummy message, say `sendMessage("Hello")`? Maybe you already tried it?

Comment: @AshutoshKS I've noticed that the Nodejs code example I used as a reference  was added in that MDN wiki page very recently, 10 days ago, and I think it has issues/needs improvement. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the `sendMessage` function from the MDN wiki page as follows, i.e.:

- no need allocating a new `Buffer` via stringifying the string/wrongly supposed as JSON, `msg`
- the 1st of the 4 bytes of the header (converted in little-endian) should take the length of the given `msg` as **string**
- the `msg` should be send using stout as it is, i.e. as **string**

```js
function sendMessage(msg) {

    var header = Buffer.alloc(4);
    header.writeUInt32LE(msg.length, 0);

    process.stdout.write(header);
    process.stdout.write(msg);

}
```

Also, here is an example message to send:

```
sendMessage('{"test": "content"}');
```

PS: I also updated that MDN wiki page with it.

Comment: Hey @darkred could you please provide a full example with Node.js? as MDN version is not working, at least I'm not able to make it working...

Comment: I had updated the example in MDN wiki page as follows: diff: https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging$compare?locale=en-US&to=1595872&from=1593969 revision: https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging$revision/1595872. That example worked fine for me. (as you may see in the the wiki page history, it has been changed 8 times by other MDN contributors since my edit)

Comment: Thank you, for the link, will check it, but looks much more readable than official one!